# Angular *ngIf not to repeat

Tags: javascript, angular

I am usung angular 9.

I have the following:

```html
    <div *ngIf="!inHistory(i,j); else else_content">1</div>
    <ng-template #else_content>2</ng-template>
```

This works perfectly, i.e. it displays either `1` or `2`.

**Question**

How do I add a third positive dic without having to call the `inHistory` function again? (and not within the original div)

e.g.

```html
    <div *ngIf="!inHistory(i,j); else else_content">1</div>
    <ng-template #else_content>2</ng-template>
    <div *ngIf="!inHistory(i,j)">3</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="isTrue()">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="true">1</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="false">2</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="true">3</div>
</div>
```

Result:
1
3

Comment: This should give the exact same output as the other solutions. For true: 1, 3. For false: 2. Are we missing something that this solution is preferred?

Comment: For interests sake, if you required a second `ngSwitch`, how would that be handled?

Comment: @jelle, it looks better, has less lines, and the order of 1, 2, 3, in de code is respected, even though in the end result has correct order anyway.

Comment: @Richard you can always nest them
```<div [ngSwitch]="isTrue()">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="true">
    <div [ngSwitch]="isTrue()">1a
      <div *ngSwitchCase="true">1b</div>
      <div *ngSwitchCase="false">2b</div>
      <div *ngSwitchCase="true">3b</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="false">2a</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="true">3a</div>
</div>```

Comment: I mean an `ngSwitch` with a different condition. e.g. `<div [ngSwitch]="isTrue()">` and `<div [secondNgSwitch]="isSomeOther()">`

Comment: Ah, you'd only need one switch I think. ```<div [ngSwitch]="isTrue() + isSomeTimesTrue() * 2">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="1">FirstConidtionTrue</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="2">SecondConditionTrue</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="3">BothTrue</div>
</div>```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the positive or negative outcome in a `ng-container` element. This element won't be rendered.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="!inHistory(i,j); else else_content">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>3</div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #else_content>
  <div>2</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Hi Jelle, thank you for the reply.  But I cannot put it within the same tag. Sorry if I was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a good practice to put `*ngif` in non UI contextual elements to seperate functionalities from Layout.
For this reason you should use `<ng-container>`

```html
 <ng-container *ngIf="!inHistory(i,j); else else_content">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>3</div>
 </ng-container>
  <ng-template #else_content>
   <div>2</div>
  </ng-template>
```

**EDIT**

Since order is important:

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="!inHistory(i,j)">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="true">1</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="false">2</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="true">3</div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I unfortunately cannot put them in the same tag. They also need to be in order of 1,2,3

Comment: could you clearify your context ? Maybe something is missing, that is important to the code context.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your query correctly, you need to display an independent third div without any condition.. right? If yes just add that without *ngIf..

```
<div *ngIf="!inHistory(i,j); else else_content">1</div>
<ng-template #else_content>2</ng-template>
<div>3</div>
```

Or if you want to add multiple blocks(successBlock in the below example) to the if case success block, just group those with an ng-template and use that template's id in *ngIf..

```
<div *ngIf="!inHistory(i,j); then successBlock else else_content">1</div>  
<ng-template #successBlock >
  <div> </div>
  <div> </div>
  <div> </div> 
</ng-template>
<ng-template #else_content>2</ng-template>
```